# Can't access internal drive from Linux bootable USB flash drive

Tags: hard-drive, bootable-media

I've been trying to install a Linux partition on my new laptop—a Dell XPS 15 9570—for dual booting, but I haven't been able to.

Whatever system I try to run from a bootable USB flash drive (gparted, Arch Linux, Kali Linux, Manjaro, Ubuntu created using either manual formatting or Windows disk imager), I am unable to access the internal hard drive to shrink the Windows partition and make a partition to boot on.

I've looked through a bunch of options in Windows and my BIOS, I've turned off a bunch of security options (BitLocker/secure boot) and booting using legacy option instead of UEFI but none have helped.

I'm feeling like this is a problem that will require reinstalling Windows to fix, but if there's a way around it I would like to know about it. Also I'm not certain I'll be able to reinstall Windows if this problem persists when trying to boot from a Windows installer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Through more fiddling with settings in BIOS, there is something going on with RAID. If I disable sata RAID (switch to AHCI), my SSD becomes visible to an external USB (nvme, with correct partitioning) as a single drive, but Windows becomes unbootable.

In the "drives" section of my BIOS config, there are 3 checkboxes: sata1, sata2, pcie SSD.

I haven't found any reference to the 2 "sata" drives outside of this configuration, and the PCIe drive appears as a single drive when accessed by a bootable USB with raid turned off, so I would guess that the RAID part of the system is some kind of bootable array using the "sata" drives that I can't access?

This is output from system information:

```
[Storage]

[Drives]

Item    Value   
Drive   C:  
Description Local Fixed Disk    
Compressed  No  
File System NTFS    
Size    460.48 GB (494,433,988,608 bytes)   
Free Space  309.09 GB (331,879,182,336 bytes)   
Volume Name OS  
Volume Serial Number    CC60CA68    

[Disks]

Item    Value   
Description Disk drive  
Manufacturer    (Standard disk drives)  
Model   KXG60ZNV512G NVMe TOSHIBA 512GB 
Bytes/Sector    512 
Media Loaded    Yes 
Media Type  Fixed hard disk 
Partitions  5   
SCSI Bus    1   
SCSI Logical Unit   0   
SCSI Port   0   
SCSI Target ID  0   
Sectors/Track   63  
Size    476.94 GB (512,105,932,800 bytes)   
Total Cylinders 62,260  
Total Sectors   1,000,206,900   
Total Tracks    15,876,300  
Tracks/Cylinder 255 
Partition   Disk #0, Partition #0   
Partition Size  650.00 MB (681,574,400 bytes)   
Partition Starting Offset   1,048,576 bytes 
Partition   Disk #0, Partition #1   
Partition Size  460.48 GB (494,433,992,704 bytes)   
Partition Starting Offset   816,840,704 bytes   
Partition   Disk #0, Partition #2   
Partition Size  990.00 MB (1,038,090,240 bytes) 
Partition Starting Offset   495,250,833,408 bytes   
Partition   Disk #0, Partition #3   
Partition Size  13.57 GB (14,568,914,944 bytes) 
Partition Starting Offset   496,288,923,648 bytes   
Partition   Disk #0, Partition #4   
Partition Size  1.17 GB (1,250,951,168 bytes)   
Partition Starting Offset   510,858,887,168 bytes   

[SCSI]

Item    Value   
Name    Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller 
Manufacturer    Microsoft   
Status  OK  
PNP Device ID   ROOT\SPACEPORT\0000 
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\spaceport.sys (10.0.17763.404, 636.52 KB (651,792 bytes), 15/04/2019 22:37) 

Name    Intel(R) Chipset SATA/PCIe RST Premium Controller   
Manufacturer    Intel Corporation   
Status  OK  
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_282A&SUBSYS_087C1028&REV_10\3&11583659&1&B8    
Memory Address  0xED590000-0xED597FFF   
Memory Address  0xED5A7000-0xED5A70FF   
I/O Port    0x00004090-0x00004097   
I/O Port    0x00004080-0x00004083   
I/O Port    0x00004060-0x0000407F   
Memory Address  0xED500000-0xED57FFFF   
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967290  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967289  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967288  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967287  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967286  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967285  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967284  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967283  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967282  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967281  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967280  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967279  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967278  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967277  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967276  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967275  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967274  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967273  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967272  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967271  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967270  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967269  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967268  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967267  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967266  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967265  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967264  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967263  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967262  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967261  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967260  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967259  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967258  
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967257  
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\iastorac.sys (17.0.2.1076, 993.47 KB (1,017,312 bytes), 16/03/2019 07:35)   

[IDE]

Item    Value   

[Printing]

Name    Driver  Port Name   Server Name 
OneNote Microsoft Software Printer Driver   Microsoft.Office.OneNote_16001.11601.20066.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe_microsoft.onenoteim_S-1-5-21-1986560419-1336647238-412034259-1001   Not Available   
Microsoft XPS Document Writer   Microsoft XPS Document Writer v4    PORTPROMPT: Not Available   
Microsoft Print to PDF  Microsoft Print To PDF  PORTPROMPT: Not Available   
Fax Microsoft Shared Fax Driver SHRFAX: Not Available   

[Problem Devices]

Device  PNP Device ID   Error Code  

[USB]

Device  PNP Device ID   
Intel(R) USB 3.1 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.10 (Microsoft)  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A36D&SUBSYS_087C1028&REV_10\3&11583659&1&A0
```

Comment: Need to know the hardware spec of the laptop - especially the hdd controller. Does it have a cdrom? If it has replace it with a hdd caddy, install another hard drive, then see if you can install to that

Comment: The drive is: KXG60ZNV512G NVMe TOSHIBA 512GB
I'm not sure if this is the controller, or how to find the controller if it isn't

I don't have an optical drive on this laptop

Comment: Need the specification of the laptop - Make and model

Comment: RAID should only be used if there is more than one hdd - Some combine the RAID name with standard AHCI mode - Do you have other options other than raid for the drive setup?

Comment: The options for the drive setup are None (sata controller is hidden), AHCI and RAID. With RAID being the default.

Comment: The reason your Windows becomes unbootable after changing is because, during install, Windows has configured the correct boot device drivers for your chosen SATA controller configuration (RAID). Switching to a different SATA controller configuration (AHCI) means Windows loads drivers for functionality it cannot control, thus fails to boot. The problem you have here is that your Linux distro isn't detecting the drive using its drivers (in RAID mode), but Windows won't boot because it's configured to use RAID. Have you tried the likes of a recent Ubuntu Live-CD?

Comment: Ubuntu has the same results, (lsblk/fdisk -l doesn't show internal hard drive)